# indices are not loading after migration

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

i am working on a ELK migration project where i have to migrate some kibana  reports from one environment to another.  following are the imporant facts of the current scenario 
1.source instance has  few reports and dashboards already running 
2.target instance is new and not having anything configured.

what i have done so far ?
imported and exported index pattern and vizualisations from source to target.
moved  the respective indices from the source  ELK machine to target ELk machine. (the folder structure in the source was **C:\busdata\rrsb\gbl0\elastic\data**)
which was not in target , i created this structure and moved the indices. but even after doing this am not able to see the indices reflecting in target kibana any help would be greatly appriciated!

## edit 1 :

1. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.15 9lKZcPp-R3mPlD9sO05WXQ 1 0   8634      0   2.1mb   2.1mb
2. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.19 cCNxYKY6Ty-yZ6yewApCOQ 1 0   8634      0   2.1mb   2.1mb
3. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.16 cfPYR03vTOemcTQgiz-S9A 1 0   8635      0   2.1mb   2.1mb
4. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.20 qtWwjtQwSKewsbG5VTUpTQ 1 0   8635      0   2.2mb   2.2mb
5. green  open .kibana_task_manager            pAZ3ZwopTsK2O4gbsyZxEA 1 0      2      0  21.4kb  21.4kb
6. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.19     Cv4vyb1wQMy9KY60R6ypDw 1 0 182067 156056    97mb    97mb
7. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.21     tj2PRrjhRya5Ug8XCPdhSA 1 0  64952  55670  35.5mb  35.5mb
8. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.18 3aRbt1cEQaCOvR3Ejoa5BA 1 0   8635      0   2.1mb   2.1mb
9. yellow open totalexecution-2019             A1STnoWdT6K08Jbzo_IrGw 1 1     88      0   153kb   153kb
10. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.21 2ACPOvgoS3qN-D-3v_Drlg 1 0   3057      0 888.1kb 888.1kb
11. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.15     QCXUD3HsSPiWPr0YvP3rJA 1 0 182067 156056  94.9mb  94.9mb
12. green  open .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.17 1OhA-n3GSommdPZR1OczoQ 1 0   8634      0   2.1mb   2.1mb
13. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.18     xNpsH4zTRAq2BKkdEb96cg 1 0 182088 156074  96.3mb  96.3mb
14. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.20     81fleytkR4eI470R8GIW_Q 1 0 182108 156056 101.9mb 101.9mb
15. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.17     UBILMFY3QJ--Av1D2_Pmvw 1 0 182067 156056  96.3mb  96.3mb
16. green  open .kibana_1                       Y-K8CD7gT6a4HAbiTKCy_g 1 0     20      2  58.3kb  58.3kb
17. green  open .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.16     KK3apwI4TEClmYZEbDIUTA 1 0 182088 156074  96.3mb  96.3mb
  18.

**logs of elastic in the path -> C:\busapps\drsb\gbl0\elastic\logs** for todays date

[2019-08-21T00:00:02,586][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [win000576.aze.xxxxxx.com] [.monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.21] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-kibana], shards [1]/[0], mappings [_doc]

[2019-08-21T00:00:06,320][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [win000576.aze.xxxxxx.com] [.monitoring-es-7-2019.08.21] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-es], shards [1]/[0], mappings [_doc]

[2019-08-21T01:00:01,179][INFO ][o.e.x.m.e.l.LocalExporter] [win000576.aze.xxxxxx.com] cleaning up [2] old indices

[2019-08-21T01:00:01,179][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [win000576.aze.xxxxxx.com] [.monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.14/V2OXt02OTZCux8CsHBfTHw] deleting index

[2019-08-21T01:00:01,179][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [win000576.aze.xxxxxx.com] [.monitoring-es-7-2019.08.14/zCIgkc8nT7K_RCWqU07xKg] deleting index

Answer (score 0):

Are the indices even being picked up by Elasticsearch? You can check with [`GET /_cat/indices`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html).

If not, I'd start looking at the log output of Elasticsearch.

And generally the safer way would be to [take a snapshot and then restore it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html).

Comment: pls see my edit . i have added the output of the cat indices command from the dev tools.

Comment: from the logs i can clearly say that those indices are none of those which i moved from the source machine. i moved four indices from the source machine.

Comment: It looks like you started with a new data directory. There is no way to merge those. Stop your cluster and replace the current data directory with the old one.

Comment: am not sure excatly what  you sugggest. let me try to understand. 
you are asking me to stop the elastic search service and replace the data directory itself bu copy and paste data directory  of the source instance

Comment: ok here it is what i have done is i have copied the folder structure of the "data" folder and pasted in the target.
but there is one important thing ...
C:\busdata\rrsb\gbl0\elastic -- this is the source structure which has this "data" folder inside 
where in  , the target there is no folder named "gb10" , i only created it  and needless to say i have created"elastic" inside it then pasted this "data" folder.

Comment: Did that work then and your node picked up your old indices?

Comment: nope it did not work still the visualizations are not picking up the indices.